# JavaScript - Perform function at the end of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a Node.js program that looks similar to this:

```
var foo = [val,val,val....]
var bar = []

for(i=0;i<foo.length;i++){
  bar.push(foo[i])
  if(bar.length % 29 == 0){

    //do something with items 1-29 of bar

  bar.length = 0;
  }
}
```

The foo array is over 1,000 items and I must perform a function with every set of 29 items in the foo array.  I am using the bar to get every 29 objects successfully and reset it to zero when I'm done.
However - I would like to perform the same function on the last items in the foo array that are less than 29.

I am not sure how to go about doing this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if (i == foo.length-1)` gets the last one

Comment: modify if statement to include `OR (i == foo.length)`

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking

Comment: And don't reset the length of the array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var foo = [val,val,val....]
var bar = []

for(i=0;i<foo.length;i++){
    bar.push(foo[i])
    if(bar.length % 29 == 0 || i == foo.length - 1){

        //do something with items 1-29 of bar

        bar.length = 0;
    }
}
```

Adding the `i == foo.length - 1` part will cause the enclosed code to be executed for the last set of items, even if there aren't exactly 29 of them. So, if `foo.length == 28`, it will execute when it reaches the 28th item. If `foo.length == 40`, it will execute on the 29th item and the 40th item.

Comment: Thanks - I am spot checking now but I think this did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
var foo = [1, 2, 3, ...]
for(i = 0; i < foo.length; i += 29) {
    var bar = foo.slice(i, i+29);
    // do something bar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for each 29 items in foo

```
var foo = [1,2,3....];
var bar = [];
for(i=0;i<foo.length;i++){  
  bar.push(foo[i]);           
  if(bar.length >= 29)  {
    // do something with bar
    bar = [];
  }  
}
if(bar.length>0) {
    // do something with remaining bar
}
```

however, you can create partitions of size N and do the same job, but elegant ;-)

```
var bar,size = 29;
for (var i=0,j=foo.length; i<j; i+=size) {
    bar= foo.slice(i,i+size);
    // do something with bar
}
```